# Lamport logical clocks. How does it start working?

Tags: c, algorithm, clock

I understand that every process has a logical clock C, a->b if C(a) < C(b). But how do they start the processes to work? Here we have an image:

[image]

Do they use messaging? We start at the process P1 and it sends a message to P2? Then what P2 does? What did P2 before getting request from P1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

P1, P2 and P3 work on the following principle:

> They all increment independently, but at different frequencies (and
>   aim for synchronization). When an event occurs, the originating process
>   sends its current value to the target process, which checks whether the value
>   received is smaller than its current value. If it is, it changes its
>   current value to received value + 1, else it discards the received
>   value.